# How can I rename files in PowerShell?

Tags: powershell

I have 2 tasks that I'd like to use PowerShell for:

1 - I also need to rename all the index.asp to Default.aspx

2 - I have a directory `C:\WWW` where I need to rename all the `.asp` files to `.aspx`, recursively.

I have tried the `Rename-Item` command but always get errors.

> Cannot create a file when that file already exists

How can I rename files in PowerShell?

Answer (score 6):

Use the `Get-ChildItem` cmdlet to get all index.asp files. Pipe the result to the `Rename-Item` cmdlet and give the files the new name.

```
Get-ChildItem c:\www -Filter Index.asp -Recurse | Where-Object {$_.Extension -eq '.asp' } | Rename-Item -NewName Default.aspx
```

, that will get you index.aspx files as well so pipe the result to the `Where-Object' cmdlet and filter based on the file extension

Do the same for asp files, notice that now you will get .aspx files as well so pipe the result to the `Where-Object' cmdlet and filter based on the file extension. in the new name, take just the base name of each file (without extension) and append it '.aspx'

```
Get-ChildItem c:\www -Filter *.asp -Recurse | Where-Object {$_.Extension -eq '.asp' } | Rename-Item -NewName {$_.BaseName + '.aspx'}
```

Comment: @Shay In your first line of code, you are filtering for Index.asp and then `Where`ing for .asp to eliminate .aspx finds. For me, filtering `Index.asp` in a directory with both `Index.asp` and `Index.aspx` only results in it finding the former; is there something that could cause these two different results, or is this just an oversight?

Comment: @SpellingD You're right, I'm getting the same results. Interesting, when you filter with a wildcard you get aspz files too but when you specify the file name you get back just asp files! Thanks for pointing this out, I will update my answer.

Comment: @Unreal1969 Glad you find it useful, consider marking it as the answer.